# vSphere - Virtual Network Device Issue

Tags: networking, vmware-vsphere

So I have network monitoring at our business and since we have been monitoring I have noticed massive spikes on one of our core switches in particular -it is causing our internal network to slow down. The problematic interfaces that are throttling data are connected to our host that runs our vSphere. We have around 60 VMs running on that one host including an RSA Authentication Server which might explain why we are having people complain about their VPN connection dropping. The hardware is handling the load fine but I have looked up possible issues and found that Old Virtual Machine Network Devices might be the issue. 
I guess im just looking for confirmation about the issue here. I have looked at all 60 odd VMs and found 36 running Flexible/E1000E/E1000 and the rest running VMXNET3. VMXNET3 is stated to be the preferred network device, would using the same virtual network device improve network performance? Or should the way it's currently set up not make much of a difference?

Answer (score 1):

> would using the same virtual network device improve network
>   performance?

VMXNET3 is, with up to date vmtools installed, easily the most efficient method to use, it should reduce your hosts CPU load but won't actually lower the amount of traffic your VMs are sending, in fact it may increase it as it's more efficient. Sounds like your switch is out of steam.

> Or should the way it's currently set up not make much of a difference?

No, do change them, it makes sense, no massive rush but it will help.

Comment: OK, good to get that confirmed, will put it on my 'to-do-list'. There shouldn't be adverse effects i should be aware off changing devices from E1000E/E1000/Flexible to VMXNET3 is there? Thanks for your time and quick response btw!

Comment: No, but if shutdown a VM, remove the e1000 and add a vmxnet3 then your vNICs may have different port enumerations so you may well have to rebuild your IP configs but that's easy enough.